# Get Oracle oradata folder from c# code?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, oracle10g, oracleclient

Is it possible to get or guess oracle's oradata folder from a C# code?

e.g. D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\oradata

My purpose is to create an installer that automatically create tablespace, but we need to ask the user where the tablespace location will be. But it would be nice if the text field can be prepopulated with the "guessed" value so that the user won't need to do anything if the guess is correct.

Answer (score 0):

The environment variable ORA_HOME is not reliable (and only valid on the server anyway).

The only way to get the definite value is through the V$PARAMETER view:

```
select value
from v$parameter
where name = 'db_create_file_dest';
```

Although I'm not 100% if this *has* to be set.

V$PARAMETER is usually not readable for regular users. But as you are going to create a tablespace I guess granting the user that privilege isn't a problem then.

But you can create a tablespace without specifying a directory for the datafile. In that case the tablespace will be created in the location specified by db_create_file_dest.

From [the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/clauses004.htm#i1030551):

> *The filename **can** include a path prefix. If you do not specify such a path prefix, then the database adds the path prefix for the default storage location, which is platform dependent.*

(Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by querying the Oracle data dictionary for the location of datafiles -- but different tablespaces may be stored in different locations.

Also:

Don't forget that the database may be configured to use ASM or Oracle Managed Files (my personal favourite) in which case it becomes more difficult or unnecessary to tell Oracle where to create the datafiles.

I would strongly suggest that tablespace creation be done outside of the installer as usage of tablespaces is something often governed by DBA policies.